# Async functions run sequential, why?

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await, es6-promise

I'm a bit confused about async functions. It says that they return a promise. A promise usually does not immediately run before the rest of the code, because javascript works with the "run to completion" approach.

But if async functions return a promise, how can you explain this?

```js
const _prefixJS = async file => {
  console.log('running...')
  fs.copyFileSync(file, `${file}.bak`);
  const content = fs.readFileSync(file, 'utf8');
  // Some modifications...
  fs.writeFileSync(file, newContent);
  console.log('stopping!')
};

console.log('start')
_prefixJS(f);
console.log('end')

// Output: start > running... > stopping! > end
```

In my opinion, the output should be: `start > end > starting... > stopping!`

Because promises run concurrently and they are placed at the end of the event loop.

I know that those methods are still synchronous, but that's not the topic. I'm currently going from synchronized nodejs-methods to async ones. I am just asking that if async methods return a promise, how is it that it runs before the `end` console.log statement?

Comment: you have zero `async` functions inside your `_prefixJS` So the browser is likely optimising out the wasteful `async` keyword.

Comment: Your code does not actually perform any async work.

Comment: Look at the `copyFileSync` function that you're using.  That **Sync** part means synchronous.

Comment: This is *cooperative* multitasking - you need to `await` somewhere to return control to the main thread.

Comment: You're using *Sync versions, which are explicitly synchronous.

Comment: @devlincarnate — Functions declared with the `async` keyword always return a promise.

Comment: @Keith Where do you see an explanation for this: `start > running... > stopping! > end`. Because I cannot find it in the comments. This question has nothing to do with the sync methods I'm currently using. But I guess it was a bit of a misleading example.

Comment: "A promise usually does not immediately run before the rest of the code" — Yes, it does. Usually, you just don't notice because the promise does something asynchronous and returns control to the parent function before there's any *measurable* change.

Comment: @Keith Ah ok sorry. Then I misinterpreted your comment.

Comment: @Quentin  Good point, but I assume he meant when a promise gets resolved.  I think the confusion might be that in the early days, I can't remember when, but promises were always assumed to be next tick, but I assume because of performance reasons this restriction was taking out.  I think people even used this side effect to clear down the stack, but with tail recursion this is likely not an issue anymore.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> But if async functions return a promise, how can you explain this?

An `async` function runs **synchronously** up to the first `await` or `return` (including implicit return). (When I say "up to," the synchronous part includes the operand to the right of `await` or `return`.) At that point (`await` or `return`), it returns a promise. That's so it can *start* whatever asynchronous process it's supposed to start. This is covered in the specification [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-async-function-definitions-EvaluateBody).

Your `_prefixJS` doesn't contain any `await` or `return`, so it synchronously runs through to the end, returning a promise that will be fulfilled with the value `undefined`.

To make your `async` function actually work asynchronously, you'd want to use the [`fs.promises`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_promises_api) version of those functions and `await` their results. Something like this (untested):

```
const fsp = require("fs").promises;
// ...
const _prefixJS = async file => {
  console.log('running...');
  await fsp.copyFile(file, `${file}.bak`);
  const content = await fsp.readFile(file, 'utf8');
  // Some modifications...
  await fsp.writeFile(file, newContent);
  console.log('stopping!');
};
```

With that function, the `console.log('running');` call and the `fsp.copyFile(...)` call are done synchronously when `_prefixJS` is called, then the function returns its promise and waits for the result of `fsp.copyFile(...)` before continuing its logic asynchronously.

Live example using placeholders for the `fsp` functions:

```js
const doWork = () => new Promise(resolve =>
    setTimeout(resolve, Math.random() * 2000));

const fsp = {
    async copyFile() {
        console.log("copyFile started");
        await doWork();
        console.log("copyFile returning");
    },
    async readFile() {
        console.log("readFile started");
        await doWork();
        console.log("readFile returning");
    },
    async writeFile() {
        console.log("writeFile started");
        await doWork();
        console.log("writeFile returning");
    }
};

const _prefixJS = async file => {
    console.log('running...');
    await fsp.copyFile(file, `${file}.bak`);
    const content = await fsp.readFile(file, 'utf8');
    // Some modifications...
    await fsp.writeFile(file, "newContent");
    console.log('stopping!');
};

console.log("calling _prefixJS");
_prefixJS()
.then(() => {
    console.log("then handler on _prefixJS()");
})
.catch(error => {
    console.log(`catch handler on _prefixJS(): ${error.message}`);
});
console.log("calling _prefixJS - done");
```